# Get Push Notifications when server is down

Tags: android, push-notification

It is possible that I can set up a **push notification** on mobile (android) when the server goes down ? That to multiple IP 's.

The services offered by *Pingdom* are very good, but extremely expensive and I need only notification (alert) and not of the other services offered .

Comment: What do you mean "when the server goes down?" Which server?

Comment: Hello . I meant my cloud server based on my server IP. The question of "when the server goes down" wanted to mention when the server does not make more ping (error 500 or error in the database). Amazom has a service that informs through push notifications if the server is slow or down . But only for servers that are hosted on the Amazon itself.